# GCloud Transcoder: Job failed when multiple videos are in editList

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

I'm trying to create a transcoder job that concatenates two videos. The job fails with "internal server error".

This is my edit list:

```js
const editList = [
    {
        key: "atom1",
        inputs: ["input0"]
    },
    {
        key: "atom2",
        inputs: ["my-input"],
    }
]
```

This is my input list:

```js
[
    {
        key: "input0",
        uri: objectUri,
    },
    {
        key: "my-input",
        uri: mySecondVideoUri,
    }
]
```

This is what the entire config looks like.

```js
{
        inputs: [
          {
            key: "input0",
            uri: objectUri,
          },
          {
            key: "my-input",
            uri: mySecondVideoUrl,
            preprocessingConfig: {},
          },
        ],
        pubsubDestination: {
          topic: PUB_SUB_DESTINATION,
        },
        elementaryStreams: [
          {
            key: "video-stream0",
            videoStream: {
              h264: {
                heightPixels: 360,
                widthPixels: 640,
                bitrateBps: 550000,
                frameRate: 60,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            key: "video-stream1",
            videoStream: {
              h264: {
                heightPixels: 720,
                widthPixels: 1280,
                bitrateBps: 2500000,
                frameRate: 60,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            key: "video-stream2",
            videoStream: {
              h264: {
                heightPixels: 1080,
                widthPixels: 1920,
                bitrateBps: 5000000,
                frameRate: 60,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            key: "audio-stream0",
            audioStream: {
              codec: "aac",
              bitrateBps: 64000,
            },
          },
          {
            key: "audio-stream1",
            audioStream: {
              codec: "aac",
              bitrateBps: 96000,
            },
          },
        ],
        muxStreams: [
          {
            key: "sd",
            container: "fmp4",
            elementaryStreams: ["video-stream0"],
          },
          {
            key: "hd",
            container: "fmp4",
            elementaryStreams: ["video-stream1"],
          },
          {
            key: "fhd",
            container: "fmp4",
            elementaryStreams: ["video-stream2"],
          },
          {
            key: "audio-0",
            container: "fmp4",
            elementaryStreams: ["audio-stream0"],
          },
          {
            key: "audio-1",
            container: "fmp4",
            elementaryStreams: ["audio-stream1"],
          },
          {
            key: "downloadable",
            container: "mp4",
            elementaryStreams: ["video-stream2", "audio-stream1"],
          },
        ],
        manifests: [
          {
            fileName: "h264.mpd",
            type: "DASH",
            muxStreams: ["sd", "hd", "fhd", "audio-0", "audio-1"],
            dash: {
              segmentReferenceScheme: "SEGMENT_LIST",
            },
          },
          {
            fileName: "h264.m3u8",
            type: "HLS",
            muxStreams: ["sd", "hd", "fhd", "audio-0", "audio-1"],
          },
        ],
        spriteSheets: [
          {
            filePrefix: "thumbnail",
            spriteHeightPixels: 720,
            spriteWidthPixels: 1280,
            totalCount: 1,
          },
        ],
        editList,
      }
```

I have tried using different videos and I made sure the videos are in the same bucket to rule out IAM access issues. From what I can tell from here https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/concatenate-videos, this should work.

If I remove either entry from the editList, the video transcodes successfully. This leads me to believe that there isn't an issue with either video individually or the rest of the config in general. Only when both items are in the list do I get a rather generic "internal" error.